# What's the difference between using a delayed_job and running rails console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, tmux, rails-console

I need to get a long running crawling task done on the server side, so I have tried to use a `delayed_job` for it, however, I've ran into problem while using the `delayed_job` with `Capybara`. So, I run the task in `rails console` instead. Since it is a long task, I use `tmux` to keep my `rails console` alive when my `ssh` connection is disconnected.

I know that using `tmux` is actually emulating me using the `rails console`. So my question is, is there a real difference between running a `delayed_job` and doing the task in `rails console`?

Does running long task in `rails console` eat up more resources on the machine, compared to a `delayed_job`, because it is running at foreground?

Is running `rails console` on `tmux` become a background service? Since I can leave it running on it's own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`delayed_job` allows for automatically executing the task as opposed to manually performing the task in the console by logging on to the server.

If it is ok for you to manually perform the task, then don't worry about automating it with `delayed_job`/`resque` or any of [the other background processing tools](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs).

Most likely this is a task that you want to accomplish on a regular basis, so it would be worthwhile to automate it as a background task. (Probably worthwhile to spend time on figuring out the delayed_job/capybara error)

The current solution of running the task in a tmux session on the server is simulating a background process (one which is manually kicked off)